# Youtube Videos PHP API 'too_many_recent_calls'

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have approx 5000 video urls in database. However some of those aren't valid youtube videos. So for cleaning the invalid videos, I am using PHP api `file_get_contents` from `"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<video id>?v=2&alt=jsonc"`

However fater some calls, I get `***'failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in xx/xx/xxxxx.php'***`

I know that is due to too_many_recent_calls. But how do I work out with this? Any alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to increase the quota limit from here: https://console.developers.google.com/project but if that isnt what you want you could just use the PHP sleep function to slow the requests to fit within your quota

Answer (score 0):

Quota limits are 50,000,000 units/day for youtube data api . 
but response of 
"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?v=2&alt=jsonc"

are containing only 50 no of video or data . it can't be increase . it might be decrees. but not increase .